# Sphero AR Example Crashes Randomly

Tags: unity-game-engine, sphero-api

I'm testing the Sphero-AR-SDK found on GitHub (https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-AR-SDK)

When testing, I seem to have random crashes on connect.

The issue I'm trying to debug is an index out of range error.

```
*"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x325102a3 0x3a22d97f 0x3245bb75 0x8cb42b 0x32e270f5 0x324e5683 0x324e4ee9 0x324e3cb7 0x32456ebd 0x32456d49 0x3602d2eb 0x3436c301 0x7f10 0x3188)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception"*
```

This happens a fair amount when booting the application but not all the time (sometimes it will get through and play the game).

I was wondering if anyone else was having issues with these random crashes or have I not set it up correctly?
I've had a look at the "Other Linker Flags" in XCode too and it has `-all_load`.

Also, I've safely checked the only place where I could find an array object access in the .mm files (RKUNBridge.mm) has this line:

```
[RKDeviceSensorsData *data = [sensors_data.dataFrames objectAtIndex:0];
```

And I safely checked this array exists and is greater than one to double check it's not this line.

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: We realized this was a bug in our AR SDK last week, unfortunately it is low level and there isn't a workaround.  We are working on getting an updated version out with a fix.  I will have the team respond here once it is out, hopefully ASAP next week.